# problemas con listas y columnas python

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for, dataframe

Hola tengo el siguiente código, donde en la parte de "filtro", filtro un programa por canal y año, y con groupby hago el promedio por dia de la columna donde viene el rating.

```
año=[2019,2020]
base2= dataframe
channels=[lista con canales]
def ran_diario(base2,año,channels):

lista=[]
df = pd.DataFrame()

for h in año:
    for i in range(1,53):
        filtro=base2[base2.Year.isin([h]) & base2.Channel.isin(channels) & base2.Week.isin([i])]  
        filtro = filtro[filtro['Description'].str.contains('[a-z]*|[a-z]*'.join(word),case=False)]
        filtro["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(filtro["Date"])      
        a=filtro.groupby("Date", as_index=False)[targets].mean()
        lista.append(a)
        df["Year"]=h
        df["Week"]=i
        df=df.append(lista,ignore_index=True)
        
return (df)
```

El output que obtengo es :

```
    Year  Week       Date           rat %
0   2020.0  52.0 2018-12-31            0.000000
1   2020.0  52.0 2019-01-01            0.000000
2   2020.0  52.0 2019-01-02            0.000000
3   2020.0  52.0 2019-01-03            0.000000
4   2020.0  52.0 2019-01-04            0.130000
..     ...   ...        ...                 ...
1      NaN   NaN 2020-01-12            0.000000
0      NaN   NaN 2020-02-01            0.066667
0      NaN   NaN 2020-02-08            0.000000
0      NaN   NaN 2020-02-15            0.035000
0      NaN   NaN 2020-02-29            0.000000
```

como se ve, la columna date y rat % estan bien pero la de year me pone al inicio año 2020 cuando es 2019 y en semana que va de acuerdo a la i del for solo pone la ultimna que es 52 y en los datos de "date" para 2020 los llena con NaN
La salida deberia ser:

```
Year  Week       Date           rat %
0   2019.0   1.0 2018-12-31            0.000000
1   2019.0   2.0 2019-01-01            0.000000
2   2019.0   3.0 2019-01-02            0.000000
3   2019.0   4.0 2019-01-03            0.000000
4   2019.0   5.0 2019-01-04            0.130000
..     ...   ...        ...                 ...
1   2020.0   1.0 2020-01-12            0.000000
0   2020.0   2.0 2020-02-01            0.066667
0   2020.0   3.0 2020-02-08            0.000000
0   2020.0   4.0 2020-02-15            0.035000
0   2020.0   5.0 2020-02-29            0.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Las asignaciones:

```
    df["Year"] = a
    df["Week"] = s
```

reemplaza toda la columna `Year` con el valor `a`, y toda la columna `Week` con el valor `s`.

Si quieres reemplazar sólo una celda, tienes que indicar el número de fila, asi

```
    df["Year"][fila] = a
    df["Week"][fila] = s
```

Sin conocer la estructura del dataframe o la lógica del problema, no puede decir cual es el valor correcto para `fila`.